# No notifications when display sleeps

Tags: notifications, sony-xperia, 8.0-oreo

I moved from iPhone to Android recently. I love it, but there are some quirks, which I am sure must just be wrong settings.

On the iPhone, when the screen is in sleep (ie off), if someone texts me, the screen wakes to the lock screen, with the text notification showing, for a moment then disappears.  This does not happen on my new Sony ZX1, using Oreo.

I have spent quite a while searching for the setting, and online, but have yet to find out why.  Is this normal for Android? If not, what am I doing wrong?  I am not in battery saver mode, and I have notifications on for texting.  In fact, no notifications move he screen from sleep to lock screen.

To be clear, the notifications do show up on the lock screen, but do not wake from sleep to show the lock screen.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Fed

Comment: Maybe try settings>apps and notifications > notification > on the lock screen > choose anything but "don't show". Let me if that works. Also check your messaging app notification settings, and see if they supposed to be shown

Comment: I am using Oreo, so the exact menu is slightly different, but yes, both are set up as you describe.  Btw, the notifications do show up on the lock screen, but do not wake from sleep to show the lock screen.

Comment: Any further suggestions?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind sorry.

Comment: Does your phone do this too? Is it normal for Android?

Comment: My phone does light up when receiving a message. Moto x4

Comment: What do you mean by light up?

Comment: I meant wakes up to the lock screen, and i can see part of the message

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted to do. I just spent a while on chat with Sony. It seems like it might be an error with 8.0. Hopefully it will be fixed in 8.1.